# routable ember-modal-dialog return to previous route

Tags: ember.js, routes

I am working on having a modal dialogue to edit address. This can be invoked from multiple routes, so my issue is that when I close the modal dialogue, I want to return to the previous route, rather than just hiding the modal. can someone help me in this regard?

Comment: Am I assuming right that you can link to your modal directly? As in it has it's own route, and you just open that route from various places to show the modal or does it work differently?

Comment: I have three scenarios from where I can trigger the Edit Address Modal dialogue route. My requirement is that, once I edit the address and save it, I need to transition to the route that I was previously on.

Scenario 1 -> edit address -> save address in controller -> return to scenario 1

Scenario 2 -> edit address -> save address in controller -> return to scenario 2

Scenario 3 -> edit address -> save address in controller -> return to scenario 3

how can I transition to the previous route after saving the address in the controller action?

Comment: I am assuming, I must change my approach and not have the Address Modal as a separate route, instead 
1. Have it defined in application.hbs, 
2. Pass the address model to the showModal action to display the address edit in the form of a modal dialogue
3. Save the address and just hide the modal dialogue

Answer (score 0):

If I understand how you've build your app then I think the answer is pretty easy, you can use `window.history.back();` from the [HistoryAPI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API) to move back to the previous item in your browsers history.

An alternative would be to remember which route you're on when you're invoking the modal and then return to that remembered route. But this should be unnecesary in your case.

I also think that a separate route for your modals is a pretty good idea since they can be linked to directly. And this approach actually helps you in solving your issue :)